# Django 1.3.1 give 1.4.1 alpha

Tags: python, django

i download django 1.3.1 from django website but it still give version 1.4 alpha when i run :

```
shox@boxLinux:$ django-admin.py --version
1.4 alpha 1
```

Comment: http://media.djangoproject.com/releases/1.3/Django-1.3.1.tar.gz

Comment: i run the file directly but still give  the same problem , also some function like generator not generate files like : manage.py

Comment: did you ever install 1.4? (for example the svn checkout example shown in the docs?)

Comment: maybe but i think its not matter coz i run django-admin.py from abs path

Comment: What does running 'which django-admin.py' give you?  I bet you are still running out of the 1.4 alpha tree.

Comment: ok if there is previous version installed where i can remove it

Comment: @j_syk : /usr/local/bin/django-admin.py

Comment: Regardless of what tree you're in, where you run the command, etc., the script will import the first `django` module it finds in the python path. Clearly, you have a django 1.4 installed somewhere in your path. You must remove it. `import django; print(django.__file__)`

Comment: @YujiTomita you are true , i run the command and i remove django in/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages and work perfectly Thanks your answer is accepted please write it as answer to accept it :).

Comment: @shox, great! I will paste it as an answer : ) I get to get rid of inline python too!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Regardless of what tree you're in, where you run the command, etc., the script will import the first django module it finds in the python path.

Clearly, you have a django 1.4 installed somewhere in your path.

You must remove it.

```
import django
print(django.__file__)
```